# Django annotate a field value to queryset

Tags: django, django-orm

I want to attach a field value (id) to a QS like below, but Django throws a 'str' object has no attribute 'lookup' error.

```
Book.objects.all().annotate(some_id='somerelation__id')
```

It seems I can get my id value using Sum()

```
Book.objects.all().annotate(something=Sum('somerelation__id'))
```

I'm wondering is there not a way to simply annotate raw field values to a QS?  Using sum() in this case doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 8):

There are at least three methods of accessing related objects in a queryset.

1. using Django's double underscore join syntax:
   If you just want to use the field of a related object as a condition in your SQL query you can refer to the field `field` on the related object `related_object` with `related_object__field`. All possible lookup types are listed in the Django documentation under [Field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups).

   ```
   Book.objects.filter(related_object__field=True)
   ```
2. using annotate with `F()`:
   You can populate an annotated field in a queryset by refering to the field with the [F()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) object. `F()` represents the field of a model or an annotated field.

   ```
   Book.objects.annotate(added_field=F("related_object__field"))
   ```
3. accessing object attributes:
   Once the queryset is evaluated, you can access related objects through attributes on that object.

   ```
   book = Book.objects.get(pk=1)
   author = book.author.name  # just one author, or…
   authors = book.author_set.values("name")  # several authors
   ```

   This triggers an additional query unless you're making use of [select_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related).

My advice is to go with solution #2 as you're already halfway down that road and I think it'll give you exactly what you're asking for. The problem you're facing right now is that you did not specify a lookup type but instead you're passing a string (`somerelation_id`) Django doesn't know what to do with.

Also, the [Django documentation on annotate()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) is pretty straight forward. You should look into that (again).

Answer (score 0):

You have `<somerelation>_id` "by default". For example `comment.user_id`. It works because `User` has many `Comments`. But if `Book` has many `Authors`, what `author_id` supposed to be in this case?