# django adding a column from a reverse one-to-many relationship on a queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, annotate

Hi i got a question lets say i got this models:

```
class Site():
   site_name = charfield

class Sample():
   site = foregeinkey
   state = decimalfield
   sample_date = datefield
```

and i need to assembly a table like this:

```
| site_name | latest_sample |
| site1     | 150           |
```

searching in the documentation an the internet [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31642425/django-annotate-a-field-value-to-queryset) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074514/django-query-that-get-most-recent-objects-from-different-categories) i found annotate for when i need to adding some other characteristics to a query set and my new query is something like:

```
class ApiGetListOfSites(View):

    def get(self, request, format=None):

    objList = Site.objects.annotate(
        date_sample=Max('sample__sample_date'),
        valor_estado=F('sample__state')
    )
    json = serializers.serialize('json', objList)
    return HttpResponse(json, content_type='application/json')
```

i got the problem that i retrieve repeated objects and no new columns in the json. some one con help me with some suggestions on how i can do this.

Ps i think if i write the query in raw SQL i can used with the raw property of django models.

Answer (score 4):

This is a typical case to use [Django Subqueries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

latest_samples = Sample.objects.filter(site=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-sample_date')
obj_list = Site.objects.annotate(state=Subquery(latest_samples.values('state')[:1]))
```

Comment: thanks very much i know now what type of query's are those. but i don't understand why the serializer only serialize the data on the Site table and don't bring the new column. i m going to see if who to doit with django-rest-framwork

Answer (score 0):

Making the table like this should work:

```
table=[]
for site in Site.objects.select_related().all():
    table.append({'site_name':site.site_name, 'latest_sample': site.sample_set.all().order_by('-pk')[0].state}
```

As pointed out by @dirkgrotten , using `select_related()` [pre-populates the cache with the related objects so it's just one query to the db](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related)

Using `select_related` without an argument should preload all related objects, or you can use the `related_name` to fetch only what you need

Comment: You could also use the date field you have in `sample_date`

Comment: That works, except you get one db query for each `site`. In this case it would help if instead of `for site in Site.objects.all()` you'd do `for site in Site.objects.all().select_related('sample_set')`